# Immutable dictionary

Tags: dictionary, julia

Is there a way to enforce a dictionary being constant?

I have a function which reads out a file for parameters (and ignores comments) and stores it in a dict:

```
function getparameters(filename::AbstractString)
    f = open(filename,"r")
    dict = Dict{AbstractString, AbstractString}()
    for ln in eachline(f)
        m = match(r"^\s*(?P<key>\w+)\s+(?P<value>[\w+-.]+)", ln) 
        if m != nothing
            dict[m[:key]] = m[:value]
        end
    end
    close(f)
    return dict
end
```

This works just fine. Since i have a lot of parameters, which i will end up using on different places, my idea was to let this dict be global. And as we all know, global variables are not that great, so i wanted to ensure that the dict and its members are immutable.

Is this a good approach? How do i do it? Do i have to do it?

---

Bonus answerable stuff :)

Is my code even ok? (it is the first thing i did with julia, and coming from c/c++ and python i have the tendencies to do things differently.) Do i need to check whether the file is actually open? Is my reading of the file "julia"-like? I could also `readall` and then use `eachmatch`. I don't see the "right way to do it" (like in python).

Comment: It is generally considered better to use `open(filename) do f ... end` syntax (see http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/functions/#do-block-syntax-for-function-arguments) than to `close` the file explicitly. For one, using the do block will clean up the file even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an ImmutableDict? It's defined in base but not exported. You use one as follows:

```
julia> id = Base.ImmutableDict("key1"=>1)
Base.ImmutableDict{String,Int64} with 1 entry:
  "key1" => 1

julia> id["key1"]
1

julia> id["key1"] = 2
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Base.ImmutableDict{String,Int64}, ::Int64, ::String)
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:234
 in macro expansion at .\REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at .\event.jl:46

julia> id2 = Base.ImmutableDict(id,"key2"=>2)
Base.ImmutableDict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "key2" => 2
  "key1" => 1

julia> id.value
1
```

You may want to define a constructor which takes in an array of pairs (or keys and values) and uses that algorithm to define the whole dict (that's the only way to do so, see the note at the bottom).

---

Just an added note, the actual internal representation is that each dictionary only contains one key-value pair, and a dictionary. The get method just walks through the dictionaries checking if it has the right value. The reason for this is because arrays are mutable: if you did a naive construction of an immutable type with a mutable field, the field is still mutable and thus while `id["key1"]=2` wouldn't work, `id.keys[1]=2` would. They go around this by not using a mutable type for holding the values (thus holding only single values) and then also holding an immutable dict. If you wanted to make this work directly on arrays, you could use something like [ImmutableArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/ImmutableArrays.jl) but I don't think that you'd get a performance advantage because you'd still have to loop through the array when checking for a key...

Comment: In 0.4.6 I get `ImmutableDict not defined` !

Comment: Base.ImmutableDict?

Comment: that's with `Base.ImmutableDict("key1"=>1)`

Comment: Then it must be v0.5- and higher. It's not exported (and not documented) so there's no guarantee it will stay either.

Answer (score 3):

**REVISION**

Thanks to Chris Rackauckas for pointing out the error in my earlier response.  I'll leave it below as an illustration of what doesn't work.  But, Chris is right, the `const` declaration doesn't actually seem to improve performance when you feed the dictionary into the function.  *Thus, see Chris' answer for the best resolution to this issue*:

```
D1 = [i => sind(i) for i = 0.0:5:3600];
const D2 = [i => sind(i) for i = 0.0:5:3600];

function test(D)
    for jdx = 1:1000
        # D[2] = 2
        for idx = 0.0:5:3600
            a = D[idx]
        end     
    end
end

## Times given after an initial run to allow for compiling
@time test(D1); # 0.017789 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
@time test(D2); # 0.015075 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

**Old Response**

If you want your dictionary to be a constant, you can use:

```
const MyDict = getparameters( .. )
```

**Update** Keep in mind though that in base Julia, unlike some other languages, it's not that you *cannot* redefine constants, instead, it's just that you get a warning when doing so.

```
julia> const a = 2
2

julia> a = 3
WARNING: redefining constant a
3

julia> a
3
```

It is odd that you don't get the constant redefinition warning when adding a new key-val pair to the dictionary.  But, you still see the performance boost from declaring it as a constant:

```
D1 = [i => sind(i) for i = 0.0:5:3600];
const D2 = [i => sind(i) for i = 0.0:5:3600];

function test1()
    for jdx = 1:1000
        for idx = 0.0:5:3600
            a = D1[idx]
        end     
    end
end


function test2()
    for jdx = 1:1000
        for idx = 0.0:5:3600
            a = D2[idx]
        end     
    end
end

## Times given after an initial run to allow for compiling
@time test1(); # 0.049204 seconds (1.44 M allocations: 22.003 MB, 5.64% gc time)
@time test2(); # 0.013657 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

Comment: but it is not. I can still add new and change pairs of `MyDict` with `MyDict[key] = value`, which is exactly what i wanted to forbid.

Comment: @hr0m Good point, but you still get the performance boost from declaring it a constant.  I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: That performance boost isn't real. It's because you're running it in the global scope but its statically typed due to const. Put it in a function an re-run the tests. Const is different from mutability because what it's really doing is telling the compiler that you won't change the type, not the values. For this reason it's not really a good answer as a true immutable structure wouldn't be able to change and can get better performance based off of that (which isn't tied to bad scoping choices)

Comment: No problem. Understanding that the REPL is at global scope and how exactly it interacts with the compiler is something that isn't too intuitive. The developers know that it causes performance issues for newcomers, and can be hard to explain. [It's one of the big issues that developers are still discussing](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8870).

Answer (score 3):

First off, I am new to Julia (I have been using/learning it since only two weeks). So do not put any confidence in what I am going to say unless it is validated by others.

The dictionary data structure `Dict` is defined here

```
julia/base/dict.jl
```

There is also a data structure called `ImmutableDict` in that file. However as `const` variables aren't actually const why would immutable dictionaries be immutable?

The comment states:

> ImmutableDict is a Dictionary implemented as an immutable linked list,
>   which is optimal for small dictionaries that are constructed over many individual insertions
>   Note that it is not possible to remove a value, although it can be partially overridden and hidden
>   by inserting a new value with the same key

So let us call what you want to define as a dictionary `UnmodifiableDict` to avoid confusion. Such object would probably have

- a similar data structure as `Dict`.
- a constructor that takes a `Dict` as input to fill its data structure.
- specialization (a new dispatch?) of the the method `setindex!` that is called by the operator [] =
  in order to forbid modification of the data structure. This should be the case of all other functions that end with `!` and hence modify the data.

As far as I understood, It is only possible to have subtypes of abstract types. Therefore you can't make `UnmodifiableDict` as a subtype of `Dict` and only redefine functions such as `setindex!`

Unfortunately this is a needed restriction for having run-time types and not compile-time types. You can't have such a good performance without a few restrictions.

**Bottom line:**

The only solution I see is to copy paste the code of the type `Dict` and its functions, replace `Dict` by `UnmodifiableDict` everywhere and modify the functions that end with `!` to raise an exception if called.

you may also want to have a look at those threads.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/n-lqjybIO_w
- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1974

Answer (score 3):

To add to the existing answers, if you like immutability and would like to get performant (but still persistent) operations which change and extend the dictionary, check out [FunctionalCollections.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/FunctionalCollections.jl)'s `PersistentHashMap` type.

If you want to maximize performance and take maximal advantage of immutability, and you don't plan on doing any operations on the dictionary whatsoever, consider implementing a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)-based dictionary. In fact, if your dictionary is a compile-time constant, these can even be computed ahead of time (using metaprogramming) and precompiled.